# Can't push object into the array after running mongodb query

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, express

I was trying to set up the logic for adding some items into an array, which id's express server receives from a client. My program receives the id of the product and then I was fetching the product details from MongoDB query findOne, and then with some customized details I used to push that item into an array but it's not working, whenever I try to push any element after MongoDB query it's not working, I don't know why, but please help me, Sorry for my bad English !

It's an ExpressJS server using MongoDB

Items received: (But it is actually received from the client in the form of JSON) :

```
const items= [
        {
            productId:"61e01e7e24612b56c33b06c3",
            quantity:"4"
        },
        {
            productId:"61e01e9024612b56c33b06c6",
            quantity:"10"
        }
    ]
```

The actual code here is the problem

```
let itemsData = [];
items.forEach(async (item) => {
    const itemData = await findProduct({ _id: item.productId });

    // Check if product found
    if (!itemData) return res.status(400).json({ message: "Product is Invalid" });

    // If found add that in object
    itemsData.push({
        productId: itemData._id,
        name: itemData.name,
        price: itemData.price,
        quantity: item.quantity,
        unit: "Nos",
        totalPrice: parseInt(itemData.price) * parseInt(item.quantity)
    });
});
```

The code above doesn't push that object into the `itemsData`
array

`findProduct` Function

```
// Service to find Product
async findProduct(filter) {
    return await ProductModel.findOne(filter);
}
```

If I used that push method and tried only to `itemsData.push("hello");` before the MongoDB query it works, but if I put it after the findProduct Query it doesn't work! I don't know what is wrong with it! Somebody help me!

I just want to push those items with detail into itemData object happily which is not happening I tried to `console.log(itemsData)` it just return `[]`, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using For Of instead of forEach (don't forget to add `async`)

```
  let itemsData = [];
  
  for (const item of items) {
    const itemData = await findProduct({ _id: item.productId });
    
    // Check if product found
    if (!itemData) return res.status(400).json({ message: "Product is Invalid" });
    
    // If found add that in object
    itemsData.push({
        productId: itemData._id,
        name: itemData.name,
        price: itemData.price,
        quantity: item.quantity,
        unit: "Nos",
        totalPrice: parseInt(itemData.price) * parseInt(item.quantity)
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you @Nacho, This worked very well without any error, I don't know why it doesn't work with the `map` answer, it was just `[undefined, undefined]`, your answer work awesome, Thanks for saving me! 

Answer (score 0):

It's  because forEach function is not designed to work well with async calls.

You could use map instead.

This should work:

```
let itemsData = [];

const promises = items.map(async (item) => {
 const itemData = await findProduct({ _id: item.productId });

 // Check if product found
 if (!itemData) return res.status(400).json({ message: "Product is Invalid" });

 return {
  productId: itemData._id,
  name: itemData.name,
  price: itemData.price,
  quantity: item.quantity,
  unit: "Nos",
  totalPrice: parseInt(itemData.price) * parseInt(item.quantity)
 };
});

itemsData = await Promise.all(promises);
```

When you use map with async, you will have an array of promises, so you can use Promise.all to wait for the values to get resolved.

Check [this](https://zellwk.com/blog/async-await-in-loops/) out for more details.

Comment: I just tried as you have advised, but after at last when I logged it in console,
it was `[undefined, undefined]`, but now it worked with for answer
Thank you sir, I was not knowing that `await Promise.all` exists, But problem solved with for statement, Thank you